# How Can I Provide Path to `MapPath()` Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm Creating a web application using Visual Studio. in that I want to save pdf that are Uploaded, to a Specific Path. So I Used Following Code

```
    String fileName = BalanceSheet.FileName;
    String fName = "pdf / Accounts / BalanceSheet/ ";
    String fname = Filename.Text;
    String location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/pdf/Accounts/BalanceSheet/";
    String filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(location,fileName);
    BalanceSheet.SaveAs(MapPath(fName+fname));
```

here `BalanceSheet` is a `FileUpload` Control. when the Following Code get executed,`BalanceSheet.SaveAs(MapPath(fName+fname));` it'Show an Exception Saying couldn't find Some parts of the Path.when I use `BalanceSheet.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));`, it Shows an Exception Saying Expecting Virtual Path.

Control

Comment: Is it typo maybe, in fName remove all empty space chars and try ~/pdf/Accounts/BalanceSheet/

Comment: Where are you trying to save files? Physical path or Virtual path? You need to provide virtual path.

Comment: @nelek Didn't work.

Comment: @MahbubMoon I want to save in this Virtual Path "pdf / Accounts / BalanceSheet/"

Comment: try using a tilde to get current domain `MapPath("~/pdf/Accounts/BalanceSheet/" + fileName)`

Comment: @MahbubMoon ("~/pdf/Accounts/BalanceSheet/" + filePath) I tried fname instead filepath.Didn't work..

Comment: It should be fileName

Comment: @MahbubMoon didn't work

Comment: You dont need AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. you can use just "~/" or "wwwroot" ant etc.

Comment: Store the result of MapPath in a variable and inspect it: is it the file path you expected?

Comment: You are not using "location" or "filePath" in your posted code

Comment: Does that "fname" folder exist? You may need to create it before saving

Comment: I managed Solve it....it was my Mistake I miss Typed Folder's Name.. Thank you for Your Supports guys.. and sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
BalanceSheet.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPtah("~/"), fName + fname);
```